# Develop a web site for an API

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, express

I'm a junior front-end developer, and I want to create a simple API. I have already a mook of this API deployed on Heroku (available on [this link](https://api-ministerios-servicios.herokuapp.com/ministerios-servicios)), developed with Express.

I want to create a website with Vue, where the root path is, logically, the website, but I also want it to have a path similar to example.com/api/v1/ministries for the API. Basically, I want to create a kind of landing page for the API.

I don't see it as something so complex, but I didn't know how to google it and, therefore, I don't know where to start.

I know how to create applications with Vue and I already have my simple API, but with the knowledge I have it would be applications raised on different servers and I don't want that.

In my mind, I should create a new app with Vue, develop it, install Express in the project and lift the API, but honestly, I don't know how to put those two steps together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please make your api in english, the person after you will thank you.

You could make an express app and move the output (dist) of your vue app in the public directory of express.

This way you'll be able to easily add routes

```
// Move vue output to folder named 'public'
// Point express to this folder
app.use(express.static('public'))

// Send the index.html (vue entrypoint) to the client on request of /
app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});
```